# Open JupyterNotebook from VScode into the Browser

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, python-3.9

I have opened my `.ipynb` file with vscode (Python 3.9 Interpreter - installed `jupyterlab`), it's connected locally, how can I open it through the browser? what is the default port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type:
`jupyter notebook` in vscode terminal (Ctrl + Shift + ~) and it will start Jupyter in browser of your preference.

If jupyter not installed type:
`pip install jupyter` in elevated powershell or however you prefer to do installs.

If pip not installed:
`python -m pip install -U pip`

if python not installed I prefer to install with chocolatey and walkthrough is on their site. https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/win/#install3-windows

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a solution, but only hints. You can let Code start a local server via Ctrl + Shift + P, then `Jupyter connect` , then select default.

Unfortunately, it's not documented how you can access the server. I gave that feedback on the documentation page.

[image]
Source of the image: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server

Comment: If in vscode I create a jupyter notebook with a kernel, does it start a jupyter server? If so, how can I find the uri of the server and can I visit this uri in web browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can list all running notebooks and their tokens by typing `jupyter notebook list` in the terminal.
It will output something like this:

```
Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8889/?token=your_token :: /directory
```

You can click on the link to open it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

## A solution for CORS-related issues:

In my case, the problem was in my CORS configuration. What fixed it for me was launching the notebook from the terminal with the allowed origin specified:

`jupyter notebook --no-browser --NotebookApp.allow_origin_pat=https://.*vscode-cdn\.net`

If, for some reason, that doesn't work, you could try the following as a last resort (bearing in mind this will allow ANY origin):

`jupyter notebook --no-browser --NotebookApp.allow_origin='*'`

Source:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Connecting-to-a-remote-Jupyter-server-from-vscode.dev